# Skip to delay observable once

Tags: angular, rxjs

With `observableTimer(0, 5000).pipe(...)` I can set the `dueTime` as a first param, so if I put 0 I won't have an initial delay.

How you can achieve same thing with `delay` operator?

```
myObservable$.pipe(
        delay(5000) // need to skip initial delay
    )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the delay conditionally:

```
.concatMap((itm, idx) => idx == 0 ? Observable.of(itm) : Observable.of(itm).delay(5000))
```

Comment: As I am on v 6.x so just did that `concatMap((value) => someInitialValue === 1 ? of(value) : of(value).pipe(delay(5000))),` seems to be working.